# How to integrate a maven project with parent pom as module?

Tags: git, maven, module, pom.xml

I'd like to use a parent maven project/aggregator to build my project and a dependency which I have in my source root as `git` submodule, e.g.

```
aggregator pom.xml
 - dependency pom.xml
 - project pom.xml
```

I naively adapted this layout from GNU C/C++ projects, like `coreutils` which simply checkout dependencies as submodules and updated them to a compatible commit together with the project state/commit.

The thing with maven is that there's a `parent` directive in `pom.xml` of the dependency and removing it would definitely require to modify the dependency which is not the intention of this setup. So, the same question asked a very different way is: **Is a `parent` directive in a pom definitely preventing a project from being used as a maven module?**. Can the warning `Some problems were encountered while building the effective model or [dependency] 'parent.relativePath' of POM [dependency] points at [aggreator] instead of org.sonatype.oss:oss-parent, please verify your project structure` be ignored?

I'm aware about the fact that this isn't the intended workflow of maven (with the local cache in mind) and that it could be easily achieved by making dependency not a maven module, but just a `git` submodule and write a two-line build script invoking `mvn` in the source root and the dependency subdirectory.

I tried using the `reactor` plugin, but it simply doesn't build anything which isn't included in `module` declaration (both the `make` and the `make-dependents` target) (error `Couldn't find project [dependency] in reactor; make sure you specified the correct group:artifactId`).

I'm using maven 3.3.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is a parent directive in a pom definitely preventing a project from being used as a maven module

No. In the end a parent is simply used to inherit stuff and it can refer to any parent. In a multimodule project parents and children point to each other (child refers to a parent, parent defines child as a module).
On the other hand: you might wonder why it is a problem that any project is used as a module. The writer of the aggregator pom probably had a reason for it.

> Can the warning Some problems were encountered while building the effective model or [dependency] 'parent.relativePath' of POM [dependency] points at [aggreator] instead of org.sonatype.oss:oss-parent, please verify your project structure be ignored?

It shouldn't be ignored, it must be set correctly, i.e. use `<relativePath></relativePath>` (empty String) in the parent.

Comment: But I'm getting `Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for [dependency] 'parent.relativePath' of POM [dependency] points at [aggreator] instead of org.sonatype.oss:oss-parent, please verify your project structure` if `parent` is specified. This is what I want to avoid.

Comment: the default relative path is ../pom.xml. In your case, set relativePath to empty String. See http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.3.3//maven-model/maven.html#class_parent

Comment: That's exactly the answer I was looking for. I'll give you the credit already and hope you'll edit accordingly.

Comment: _"In a multimodule project parents and children point to each other (child refers to a parent, parent defines child as a module)"_ can be but isn't necessarily so. See [POM Reference, Inheritance v. Aggregation](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Inheritance_v) : _"However, although both POM projects, an aggregator project and a parent project are not one in the same and should not be confused. A POM project may be inherited from - but does not necessarily have - any modules that it aggregates. Conversely, a POM project may aggregate projects that do not inherit from it."_